# Using JComboBox as a search box

Tags: java, swing, search, jcombobox

Im using a `JComboBox` to search a query from a sql database. Here is my code.

```
private void srKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){
    sr.removeAllItems();
    String sch = ((JTextField)sr.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();
    String schh = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '" + sch + "%';";
    search = conn.getQuery(schh);
    try {
        while (search.next()) {
            String item = search.getString("name");
            sr.addItem(item);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dataprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    sr.setSelectedItem(null);
    sr.setPopupVisible(true);

    System.out.println(sch);
}
```

`sr` = JComboBox

But when i type  a letter in combobox, it adds all the items in database. I came to know that `System.out.println(sch);` always gives an empty string. And as soon as i type a letter, the text field of combo box becomes empty(i cant type a word with two letters).  How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: removeAllItems probably clears the editor (didn't dig, though)

Comment: Maybe simply try to set the text back on the editor, after adding all items and showing the popup? `removeAllItems()` will indeed clear the text

Comment: Not a good idea to perform DB queries on the Event dispatch thread, and certainly not on each keystroke. Further, why do you have access to that `KeyEvent`. The editor of a `JComboBox` supports `DocumentListener`s which are almost always the better option

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, it clears the editor. But removing it doesnt resolve the problem.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I tried it also. The reason is that, editable combo box does not act as a `JTextField`. `sr.setSelectedItem(null);` makes non selected and field is empty.

Comment: @Robin Thank you for your comment. can you post the code replacedwith `DocumentListner` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons for your problems are the following:

1. `sch` is always empty is because you are calling `sr.removeAllItems();` before you call `String sch = ((JTextField)sr.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();`. This means that the contents of the `JComboBox` is cleared (along with the selection) before you get what is selected.

   Solution: Call `sr.removeAllItems();`AFTER you have got the selected item.
2. The combo box becomes empty because you call `sr.setSelectedItem(null);` at the end after you have repopulated it.

   Solution: If you want the entered text then `sr.getEditor().setItem(scr);`

Only and idea but try to enclose the contents of the method in an `if statement` and check if the `Enter key` is pressed. That way the method contents will only execute after the desired string is input and not EVERY time a key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ActionListener` instead of the looking for the key press.  When a combobox's selection is edited it will fire an `ActionEvent` when the editing is done.

When you get this part working, you should move this logic off to another thread and populate the combobox's items when it returns.  Otherwise your UI will hang while the SQL query occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. This code works fine.

```
  private void srKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){

    String sch = ((JTextField)sr.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();
    String schh = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '" + sch + "%';";
    search = conn.getQuery(schh);
    sr.removeAllItems();
    try {
        while (search.next()) {
            String item = search.getString("name");
            sr.addItem(item);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dataprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(sch);
    sr.setSelectedItem(null);
    sr.setPopupVisible(true);
    ((JTextField)sr.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setText(sch);
  }
```

Thanks to Skepi,Kleopatra, Guillaume Polet