# JComboBox loading with KeyRelease

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox, keyrelease

here my requirement is when I type something in combo box it should search the DB and get related data.when I'm typing it should fix to the exact data removing unwanted values..Here is my code..nothing happen

```
private void ComboItemName() {
    bbb = false;
    txtComboItemName = (JTextField) ComboItemName.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    txtComboItemName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
            if (!(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                try {
                    S3 = txtComboItemName.getText();
                    ResultSet rst = new JDBC.DB().getData("select * from item_reg where id like '%" + S3 + "'");
                    boolean b = rst.next();
                    boolean bb = false;
                    if (b) {
                        ComboItemName.removeAllItems();
                        bb = true;
                    }
                    while (b) {
                        if (rst.getString(1).startsWith(S3)) {
                            ComboItemName.addItem(rst.getString(1));
                        }
                        b = rst.next();
                    }
                    ComboItemName.setSelectedItem(S3);
                    txtComboItemName.setCaretPosition((ComboItemName.getSelectedItem() + "").length());
                    ComboItemName.showPopup();
                    int i = ComboItemName.getItemCount();

                    if (i > ComboItemName.getMaximumRowCount()) {
                        ComboItemName.setMaximumRowCount(15);
                    } else {
                        ComboItemName.setMaximumRowCount(i);
                    }
                    bbb = true;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }

            } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && bbb == true) {

                boolean bIT = false;

                String Sr123 = (String) ComboItemName.getSelectedItem();
                try {
                    ResultSet Rst23 = new JDBC.DB().getData("select id from item_reg");
                    while (Rst23.next()) {
                        if (Sr123.equals(Rst23.getString(1))) {
                            bIT = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            bIT = false;
                        }
                    }
                    bbb = false;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's likely the key event is being consumed, verify that keyReleased is actually being called

Comment: Use a DocumentListerner if you're only interested in knowing when new content is added to the field or a DocuemntFilter of you wish to filter what is going to the field

Answer (score 0):

is this
`ResultSet rst = new JDBC.DB().getData("select * from item_reg where id like '%" + S3 + "'");` query working fine ??

Check the value of `b`.

```
boolean b = rst.next();
```

May be your query is not working.

Comment: when I add sout under that sql like this

Comment: String y = rst.getString(1);
    System.out.println(y);

It returns this

java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set

what does this mean

Comment: Do this. Just after the `boolean b = rst.next();` line print the value of `b` and check it is `true` or `false`

Comment: The `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set` comes because your `rst` is empty. Check your query is working fine or not.

Comment: then your result set `rset` is not empty. 
`String y = rst.getString(1); System.out.println(y);` should print the element. 
Since the result will depend on your text box value, check both are the same as the previous one (when you got the error `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set` )

Comment: add the below code and check again. If b is true value should get printed. 
`System.out.println(b); 
String y = rst.getString(1); 
System.out.println(y);`

Comment: it returns true.But when I erase combo box sometime it shows item ids.sometime a while loop is running without unstopping..I don't know what to do.

Comment: after it returns true by `System.out.println(b);` what will be print by `String y = rst.getString(1); System.out.println(y);`

Comment: there is an item in my item_reg table hdd01 when I type that no respond but when I delete that character by character hdd01 true hdd01 true like that sout prints.when it is completely deleted all my item ids load to combo box

Comment: Try `public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt);` instead of `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt);` 

and `when it is completely deleted all my item ids load to combo box` it is normal.

Comment: same result there is a while loop running background so pc gets slow and struck

Comment: did you see the madprogrammers comment above he said key event consumed verify it

Comment: consumed means when you press the key it can be consumed by another event or something. If so the relevant listener will not respond. (Don't know much about it)

Comment: to consume use this.
`public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) { evt.consume(); ....`  Check that. lets see what it will do.

Comment: so what should I do..do you have any other way to do this.any code..?

Comment: `S3 = txtComboItemName.getText();`
print S3 here and check the String is read fine.
`ResultSet rst = new JDBC.DB().getData("select * from item_reg where id like '%" + S3 + "'");`

Comment: did you check the modification `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) { evt.consume(); ....`  ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218749/using-jcombobox-as-a-search-box)

Comment: S3 get that value but there are more than 10 sout prints what that means

Comment: hmmm. Check the link i commented above. It contain a solution which i think suits for you. Try that out.

Comment: access the DB is time consuming, If the DB is not changing for a while you can load the combo box once and use autocompletion. See [this](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681977/jcombobox-autocomplete)