# JComboBox as search field

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218749/using-jcombobox-as-a-search-box) first and edited like this..same combobox name.but when I call this method it ask for a keyEvent..for that what should I do.and is there any wrong with this code

```
ResultSet rset;
public void srKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){

    String sch = ((JTextField)ComboItemName.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();

    try {
        rset = new JDBC.DB().getData("SELECT * FROM item_reg WHERE id = '"+sch+"'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    ComboItemName.removeAllItems();
    try {
        while (rset.next()) {
            String item = rset.getString("id");
            ComboItemName.addItem(item);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        //Logger.getLogger(dataprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(sch);
    ComboItemName.setSelectedItem(null);
    ComboItemName.setPopupVisible(true);
    ((JTextField)ComboItemName.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setText(sch);
}
```

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` instead of `KeyListener`

Comment: Here I want ID to be drop down from DB,table item_reg

Comment: for that what part of the code should be edit

Comment: Where you are attaching a `KeyListener`, you need to get the editor and attach a `DocumentListener` instead, it is more likely to provide you more accurate information

Comment: I call this method in my combobox action perform srKeyTyped(null);  for this null value what should I give

Comment: Since you're ignoring the `evt` object anyway, it shouldn't matter...But I would change the method so that it takes no parameters

Comment: where is sql query..@

Comment: I got this exception

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

Comment: Try and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {srKeyTyped(null);}});` within your `actionPerformed` method to ensure that you are not caught up in some other events

Comment: what about the class you provide I write sql code to insertUpdate and add item to cb(combobox)..I got the exception from that

Comment: Please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection issues `"SELECT * FROM item_reg WHERE id = '"+sch+"'"` is inherently insecure as you can break out of that statement rather easily.