# Updating JTable when selecting item in combobox in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, combobox

I coded auto suggesting comboBox that retrieve data from SQL database.It was successful.

Then as next step, I want these functionalities to be done,

***When user select a "ItemID" from the comboBox**(When the user type first letter of ItemID, suggest list comes and user can select aItemID - successfully coded), **JTable's** **"ItemID" column and other columns that related to that specific "ItemID" must be updated from the database.**

I coded `updateTable()`method as below;

```
private void updateTable(){
String existID = (String) IDcombo.getSelectedItem();
String sql = "select * from druginfo WHERE ItemId LIKE '"+existID+"%'";
try {
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    saleTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
} }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JComboBox as a search box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218749/using-jcombobox-as-a-search-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your tablemodel needs to fire according to the event. If only table data changes then it should fire fireTableDataChanged(). If data and structure both changes then it should fire fireTableStructureChanged(). You can refer to the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)

If you're still having trouble with this the one way is to call repaint on your table but that's not a very good way of doing things.